# Place picture into spread sheet to fill the whole cell (Merged cells)

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Hi i am using EPPlus to populate a spreadsheet with data, so far so good text wise but i am having issues when trying to add a picture??

I can add a picture but its from the top left cell and its not contained with in a cell.

Please could someone show me how i can place a picture into a cell and fill the cell?

```
 Bitmap image = new Bitmap(tempFolderPathAlt + "ExtractedFiles/" + ArrayNode[i].TagValue);
 ExcelPicture picture = null;
 var rowIndex = xlWorkSeet1[k].Dimension.Start.Row;
 var columnIndex = xlWorkSeet1[k].Dimension.Start.Column;
 picture = xlWorkSeet1[k].Drawings.AddPicture(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + rowIndex.ToString() + columnIndex.ToString(), image);
 picture.From.Column = columnIndex;
 picture.From.Row = rowIndex;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way to add a picture into a cell.
The work around for this is to resize the cell to be the same size as your image and place it over the cell.